# Uniform distributed success probability for a coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, binomial-distribution

$n\in \Bbb N$. Let $X_1 \sim \text{Uni}_{(0,1)}$ and $X_2 \sim \text{Bin}_{n, X_1}$ conditional on $X_1$. I want to find the distribution function of the law of $X_1$ given $X_2 = k$, i.e. $\Bbb P (X_1 \leq t \ \vert \ X_2 = k )$, where $k\in \{1, \ldots , n\}$.

Comment: Use the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: Just use the Law of Total Probability, and Bayes' Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We compute
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}(X_1\in(p,p+\mathrm{d}p), X_2=k)\\
&=\mathbb{P}[X_1\in(p,p+\mathrm{d}p)]\mathbb{P}[X_2=k\mid X_1\in(p,p+\mathrm{d}p)]\\
&=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\mathrm{d}p
\end{align*}
so $X_1\mid X_2$ is a $\operatorname{Beta}(X_2+1,n-X_2+1)$-distributed random variable.

Since Uniform(0,1) is another name for $\operatorname{Beta}(1,1)$, this example is a special case of a [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior).

Comment: I am not really d'accord with your notation $\in (p, p + \text d p)$ but all in all this helped me to complete my task.

Comment: Yeah, it is not the best notation, but at least this avoids conditioning on null event $X_1=p$.

Comment: Ah, it is another notation for the densities.